# Perl command not executing because of too many arguments, how can I fix it to allow more arguments?

Tags: linux, perl, command

I am trying to use this command:

```
perl -i -p -e "s/\r//" ./{folderName}/*.txt
```

The problem is I have a lot of .txt files within this folder and I guess the command cannot handle it... Is there something else I can try or do to fix this?

The error I get is: "Argument list too long"

I've used this command successfully with smaller folder sizes (less .txt files) and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU:

```
find {folder_name} -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -exec perl -i -pe's/\r//' {} +
```

More portable:

```
find {folder_name} -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -print | xargs perl -i -pe's/\r//'

echo {folder_name}/*.txt | xargs perl -i -pe's/\r//'

find {folder_name} -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -exec perl -i -pe's/\r//' {} \;
```

Notes

- None of the solutions support a `{folder_name}` that start with `-`.
- The first two portable solutions don't support file names with some special characters in them. (But it's unlikely that you'll find those characters in file names in the first place.)
- The GNU solution and the first two portable solutions pass as many file names to `perl` as possible (minimizing the number of times `perl` is launched), while the third portable solution launches a `perl` process for every parameter.
- `echo` is a shell builtin, so it's not subject to the system's limit on the number of parameters passed to utilities.

Answer (score 4):

There is limit on input argument on shell.
This can be find by running below command.

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

If argument number are more then you can use other methods like pipe or for loop.

as example

```
for txt in ./{folderName}/*.txt ; do perl -i -p -e "s/\r//" "$txt"; done
```

or using pipe

```
echo ./{folderName}/*.txt | xargs perl -i -p -e "s/\r//"
```

explanation for echo as @ikegami raised why echo won't give "too many argument"

reason is echo is builtin command and don't pass arguments to new process.

Comment: echo is shell builtin command and don't pass the arguments  to other process so with echo it will work but not with ls,